# Embed html element value to ruby on rails link

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this ruby on rails link `<%= link_to au.name, active_academic_titles_path(:academic_unit_id => au.id, :exam_period_id => ELEMENT_VALUE ), :remote => true, :class=>"menu-units" %>`, in a html.erb view. I would like to put the value of a html element to this link.

I tried doing this `<%= link_to au.name, active_academic_titles_path(:academic_unit_id => au.id, :exam_period_id => %> ELEMENT_VALUE <%= ), :remote => true, :class=>"menu-units" %>`,

and i get this error
`/student_exams/app/views/exams/_academic_units.html.erb:5: syntax error, unexpected ')' ... => au.id, :exam_period_id => );@output_buffer.safe_append='... ... ^ /student_exams/app/views/exams/_academic_units.html.erb:5: syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting ')' ...t_buffer.append=( ), :remote => true, :class=>"menu-units... ... ^ /student_exams/app/views/exams/_academic_units.html.erb:5: Can't assign to true ...er.append=( ), :remote => true, :class=>"menu-units" );@o... ... ^ /student_exams/app/views/exams/_academic_units.html.erb:5: syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting :: or '[' or '.' ...=( ), :remote => true, :class=>"menu-units" );@output_buf... ... ^ /student_exams/app/views/exams/_academic_units.html.erb:12: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block, expecting keyword_end '.freeze; AcademicUnit.all.each do | au | ^ /student_exams/app/views/exams/_academic_units.html.erb:22: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input`

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the error that you are getting.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question what is `ELEMENT_VALUE` in this context? Expected input, output, and even sometimes workflow is very useful when asking a question as we will be able to assist much faster and more efficiently.

Comment: I have a dropdown list and each item in the list has an id value, that would be the element value

Comment: You mean, the link will change when the value of dropdown change?

Comment: yes, the link could change

Comment: It looks like you're trying to stop ERB mid-statement. Why? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: because i want to put the value of the dropdown list element in the link

Comment: You do realize that the ERB is rendered on your server before the user can select any values? You need to use javascript to link the two elements together.